Why mysqli_fetch_assoc reports an exception from a nested loop
I'm using the following code example:
$ca=$db->query('SELECT * FROM `clients`');
while ($c=$ca->fetch_assoc())
{
    try {
        $mysqli->query('ALTER TABLE `client_'.$c['id'].'_data` ADD COLUMN `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL');
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        // handling/ignoring the exception
    }
}

So in this case - some clients' table already have column "updated" and some don't.
So when one of the tables has already this column I receive an exception as expected, which I then ignore. But when I ignore this error in line 4 - after the exception happens - when the cycle tries to do the next $c=$ca->fetch_assoc - script crashes with same exception
I receive something like that
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate column .....
Stack trace:
#0 /home/api/www/test.php(2): mysqli_result->fetch_assoc()
#1 {main} thrown in /home/api/www/test.php on line 2

This exception doesn't have anything to do with $c=$ca->fetch_assoc() code. It's related to the query inside the loop and I handle this exception but it looks like it somehow is stored in mysqli error stack and the next fetch_assoc sees it and the script crashes.
I must say that the table structure in this example doesn't matter - so I attached an example without all these tables - just to simplify understanding the issue.
Example on phpize
Of course, I can prevent using fetch_assoc in the cycle but I don't want to because there are many cases when I have such constructions and I don't want to use big arrays to store all the results in them.
Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I believe you have discovered a bug in mysqli. It looks like the bug has existed since at least PHP 7.4 and has not been fixed until now.
To understand this, you need to understand that mysqli keeps the error code and message from the last executed command in a "property" of the mysqli class. When the exception mode is enabled (by default since PHP 8.1), each mysqli function checks for the error code and if it's not 0, it throws an exception. This means that mysqli internally does the following automatically:
$mysqli->query(/*...*/);
if ($mysqli->errno !== 0) {
    throw new mysqli_sql_exception($mysqli->error, $mysqli->errno);
}

The values stored in these properties are cleared before every command.
When it comes to fetch_* functions, they will only execute a command to the server if in unbuffered mode. Unbuffered mode blocks the connection, so there is no way of creating a situation like this. The only possible erroneous scenario is if the server stops responding to the fetch requests. A fix was added in PHP 7.4.26 in mysqli to throw an exception if that ever happens. But a buffered fetch will never end up in an erroneous situation. And that's how we end up in the current situation: we've got code to throw an exception in a function that doesn't clear the error code prior to its execution.
A potential fix for this will probably be to treat all fetch operations as commands and clear the error status every time.
The code example you provided is not very contrived, but I can't see an easy way to provide you with a temporary fix other than the one you already mentioned: load all rows into an array and discard the mysqli result. I believe it shouldn't use any extra memory since all rows are already in PHP memory. If you really don't want to do that then you can try some esoteric solution to clear the error status such as executing $mysqli->query('DO 1'); in your catch block.
